# Magnitude of Charge Due to Polarization

Tags: electrostatics, charge, polarization, dielectric

Quick question about polarization. If a negatively charged sphere is brought near a human, the human polarizes. Since the human is grounded, electrons, repelled by the sphere, will escape into the ground, thus leaving the human with a net positive charge. I am slightly confused about the magnitude of this charge, however. Will the positive charge on the human be equal to, greater than, or less than in magnitude to the charge of the sphere?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to think about field lines!
Field lines have to start somewhere and finish up on the negatively charged sphere.
So your question is really about how many field lines that end up on the sphere started from the human.
That will depend on the proximity of other objects and the human to the charged sphere.
Put the sphere above the human's head with nothing else around and probably (almost) all the field lines finishing up on the sphere will come from the human, but that will not be so if the sphere is placed near the ground as there will be field lines between the ground and the sphere.